# How to make a connection string for Microsoft SQL Server on another machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I can't figure out how to make a connection string to access a database on another machine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and when I copy the connection string from the server explorer it's pointing to the `.mdf` file on my computer, so that's clearly only going to work on my host machine (that is my computer).

Here's the connection string:

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-42N6RDI; Initial Catalog=Database1");
```

I believe I don't need to specify the user id and the password.

I've tried to add the port, and I've also tried to add the ip instead of the server name but it just doesn't work.

The error I'm getting is always the same:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**EDIT**: It also says "Inner Exception"

> Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you access the server instance using SSMS or some other tool from the same machine where your code is running? What edition (Express, Developer, etc.) is the server instance?

Comment: The gold standard of connection string references: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I don't know where to see what edition I have but I have the default service based database from visual studio 2022. I am going to install SSMS right now to see if I can access it.

Comment: "it's pointing to the .mdf file on my computer" are you using LocalDB or a full installation of SQL Server? Are you using `AttachDbFilename`?

Comment: I don't believe it's a full installation, but I also just tried with a `mySQL` database and the same is happening. Yes I used AttachDbFilename.

Comment: I just setup SSMS and created the server and the database. But It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using the connection string format described [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). If you are on a domain and will be using the logged-in account on the client to access the SQL server you can use a trusted connection

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Otherwise you'll need to provide credentials.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Is the server address the name of my server or is it my ip address?

Comment: @Darkon The server, and preferably use the machine name, not the IP address

Comment: I have been trying to figure out for hours what user id and password am I supposed to enter? Windows Credentials? Microsoft Credentials? Some random sample? Specified Credentials in SSMS? help!